# How can I read/load images in C++?

Tags: c++, image

i am more a java developer and there is a standard way of reading images :

```
    BufferedImage img = null;
try {
    img = ImageIO.read(new File("strawberry.png"));
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```

but what is the c++ way of loading images?  I want to load all images in a specific directory into an array or so.

Comment: There is no standard way of doing this in C++ - the C++ Standard Library has no support for images. You will have to use one of the many non-standard image handling libraries.

Comment: Please specify OS. There's no image handling in C++ proper.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth I know that there is no standard way.what is the most common way?

Comment: @Seva Alekseyev : i'd prefer cross-platform.But Linux only is also ok

Comment: Do you want to display the images on screen? If so then please mention what GUI library you're using.

Comment: @Artelius : No. Displaying is not required

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Personally, I prefer the [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/) library.

There are many available graphics processing libraries, and there is not a single choice that stands out as clearly superior to the others.  My advice is to make a short list of 3 or 4, take a look at the documentation for each, and try to write a simple half-page program with each. Use whichever one you personally find easiest to use.

Answer (score 8):

There is no standard "way" in C++ to load images or files of any other sort. That feature is provided by (usually third-party) *libraries*.

On Windows, you can use the GDI or DirectX APIs to load images to memory.

You can also use any of many different libraries. Some that come to mind:

- [SDL-Image](http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/)
- [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/)
- [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/)'s [QImageReader](http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.6/qimagereader.html)
- [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/)
- [cImg](http://cimg.sf.net) (Which will try to read files if the appropriate filetype-specific library is available.)
- [Boost.GIL](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/gil/doc/index.html) (Which, apparently, has support for JPEG, PNG, and TIFF files.)

There are many, many others to look at, and some may be more appropriate than others depending on what you're trying to do.

For example, if you're only going to be working with JPEG files, then you'll want to use [libIJG](http://www.ijg.org/). Or if you'll only be using PNG, you might find [libPNG](http://www.libpng.org/) or [cairo](http://www.cairographics.org/) to be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

The library you will want to use to load images will depend on what you intend to do with it. If you are using a framework such as QT or wxWidgets, it will provide image loading routines.

Another possibility is to use the the [SDL Image](http://jcatki.no-ip.org:8080/SDL_image/SDL_image_frame.html) library, and to work on SDL surfaces, which will allow you to work down to the pixel level if you need.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [DevIL](http://openil.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1):

[Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/products) has good support for images, and is free and cross-platform.

Check out the [qimage class](http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.6/qimage.html)

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the closest you'll get to a standard way of doing this is with the [Boost/Adobe Generic Image Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/gil/doc/index.html).